# Pyspark String Type to Array column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark df column like this:

```
["100075010", "100075010", "100075010"]
```

It's StringType.

I wanna cast this column datatype to Arraytype.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html)

```
df = df.withColumn('col', F.from_json('col', 'array<string>'))
```

---

```
+--------------------+
|                 col|
+--------------------+
|[100075010, 10007...|
+--------------------+
```